# Timed background color change

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I change this script from jQuery to JavaScript? I have little experience with JavaScript and I don't know how to change it myself.

Script:

```
var rotate = function() {$("#Top")
.delay(1000).queue(function() {
    $(this).css({
        "background-color": "red"
    });
    $(this).dequeue();
})
.delay(3000).queue(function() {
    $(this).css({
        "background-color": "green"
    });
    $(this).dequeue();
})
.delay(500).queue(function(next) {
    $(this).css({
        "background-color": "blue"
    });
    $(this).dequeue();
    next();
})
.queue(rotate);
};
rotate();
```

Html

```
<div id="Top"></div>
```

Original: http://jsfiddle.net/h4KL7/1/

Comment: Using `setTimeout()` and `clearInterval()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John Resig is the guy who wrote jQuery and here is a blurb about [How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).

I know it is not perfect and could use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` to be more efficient, but this is a start <kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/h4KL7/172/)</kbd>

```
var rotate = function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('Top');
    setTimeout(function () {
        el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        setTimeout(function () {
            el.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            setTimeout(function () {
                el.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
                rotate();
            }, 500);
        }, 3000);
    }, 1000);
}
```

---

**Update:** Added an array to reference timeout IDs to ensure that duplicates are not created in case time gets out of sync.

```
var rotate = function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('Top');
    var timers = new Array(3);

    function red(el) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        timers[0] = setTimeout(function () { green(el); }, 1000);
        clearTimeout(timers[2]);
    }

    function green(el) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        timers[1] = setTimeout(function () { blue(el); }, 3000);
        clearTimeout(timers[0]);
    }

    function blue(el) {
        el.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        timers[2] = setTimeout(function () { red(el); }, 500);
        clearTimeout(timers[1]);
    }

    red(el);
};

rotate();
```

Comment: Is there a way you can get that script working with iframes? Like change the src instead of set a different style each time?

Answer (score 0):

The title of your post should be: "How can I change this from jQuery to CSS" ;-)

```
@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
  0% { background: #FFABAB; }
  20% { background: #FFDAAB; }
  40% { background: #DDFFAB; }
  60% { background: #ABE4FF; }
  80% { background: #D9ABFF; }
  100% { background: #FFABAB; }
}

.top {
  min-height: 200px;
  -webkit-animation: rainbow 10s infinite steps(1);
}
```

If you want to have smooth transition between your background color just omit the steps(1) in the animation shorthand property.

[Check this out!](http://jsbin.com/bebit/2/edit)